# Removing folders with a batch-file

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file

You will probably recognize the script below especially this command which was posted here over a year ago:

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /a:d /s /b *PGP Corporation*') do echo rd /s %%i
```

However, I am running into issues with it because it isn't recognizing `PGP Corporation`, all it sees is `PGP` I tried quotation marks but it didn’t help. Any Ideas?

```
@echo off
cls
echo searching for pgp corp folders
cd c:\users
for /f %%i in ('dir /a:d /s /b *PGP Corporation*') do echo rd /s %%i
echo are these the folders you want to delete? 
choice /t 15 /d n /M "Do you want to delete these folders type y for yes"
if errorlevel 2 goto no
if errorlevel 1 goto yes
goto end

:no
echo you slelected no
pause
goto end

:yes
echo you selected yes and the folders will be deleted
for /f %%i in ('dir /a:d /s /b *PGP Corporation*') do rd /s /q %%i

choice /t 15 /d n /m "Do you want to try and install PGP 10.3 now?
if errorlevel 2 goto noo
if errorlevel 1 goto yess

:noo
echo you selected not to instal. Goodbye.
goto end

:yess
echo Installation of PGP will begin Momentarily
"\\dts\apps\PGP\PGP Latest\pgp 103 64bit.msi"

pause
```

Comment: Who are you talking to?  Who's "You"? :)  You say you tried quotation marks, but that' shard to know what you mean exactly, can you provide the ACTUAL code you tried to use?

Answer (score 1):

Your folder has spaces in it, so you need to both wrap it in double-quotation marks (in both the `for` command and the `do` command), and specify that the `for` loop is not to use spaces as delimiters with the `delims` option:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /a:d /s /b "*PGP Corporation*"') do echo rd /s "%%i"
```

Comment: I suggest using `"%%~i"` instead of simply `"%%~i"`, because some windows versions yield quoted value for the `for` variable, some don't. If yielded value will be quoted, `"%%i"` will produce double-double quotes, which may lead to side effects. `%%~i` is always unquoted.

Comment: Good point. Yes, you should check that as well. In fact, this is why you should always preface your commands with an `echo` so that you can verify everything is correct before performing the actual changes because unexpected interactions like this can crop up sometimes.